# Filtering a data frame according to values rank

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df) such as

```
group  value
a      4.2
a      4.5
a      6.2
b      5.1
b      3.5
a      4.2
a      5.1
b      6.4
b      3.3
b      4.1
a      5.0
```

The desired output is

```
group  value
a      4.5
a      6.2  
a      5.1
a      5.0
b      5.1
b      6.4
b      4.1
```

Namely, desired output extracts the smallest 2 "value"s of each "group". For example,

- 4.2 and 4.2 are the smallest two values of group a, and
- 3.5 and 3.3 are the two smallest values of group b.

The desired output includes all rows of df except related rows to these values. How can I do that with R? I will be vey glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using package data.table and partial sorting:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, sort(value, partial = 2)[1:2], by = group]
#   group  V1
#1:     a 4.2
#2:     a 4.2
#3:     b 3.3
#4:     b 3.5

DF[, sort(value, partial = 2)[-(1:2)], by = group]
#   group  V1
#1:     a 6.2
#2:     a 4.5
#3:     a 5.1
#4:     a 5.0
#5:     b 6.4
#6:     b 5.1
#7:     b 4.1
```

Of course, one of the many, many alternatives for split-apply-combine type operations could be used instead.

Comment: I think OP requires all rows except these rows, i.e., `dt[order(group), .SD[!(1:2)], by=group]`

Comment: @Arun Fair enough. Do you think `forder` can beat partial sorting?

Answer (score 2):

An option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   arrange(value) %>%
   slice(-(1:2))
```

Or

```
 df %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter(rank(value, ties.method='max')>2)
```

Comment: `slice(-(1:2))` could be potentially faster than `filter(row_number()>2)`, though didn't check. BTW, congrats for making to the top 20 in [tag:r]

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I was trying to find if I can use `dense_rank` or something else without the arrange step.   It does work.